# What is the best way to detect all ways of closing a form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, formclosing

I have a form that i close using `End` several times in my code. I want to do a command to save settings when I do this called `VarsToIni()` which takes some public variables and saves them in an INI file. I have tried putting it in the main window's FormClosing (which stays open throughout) and this only works when you close from pressing the X button not from my `End` statement.

Comment: The best way to detect all ways of closing a form is to NOT call `End`.  Just close the main form.  Also, INI files are a legacy technology, try using the settings in your "My Project" tab, if possible.

Comment: The obvious answer is to not close your form with `End`. This is what the `Form.Close` method is for.

Comment: @LarsTech I didn't like the My.Settings thing so decided to switch back to INI. It makes it easier for other applications (like the installer) to read.

Comment: The `End` statement is a rude abort, same thing as Environment.Exit().  Splat, the end, no events.  Don't use it if you don't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new Sub and replace calls to `End` with calls to your new Sub:

```
Sub EndMe()
    VarsToIni()
    Application.Exit() 
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

As Dan points out, `End()` is a bad way to close the application, `Application.Exit()` is preferred.

Comment: Then you are still calling `End`... IMO `End` < `Application.Exit()` with `Shutdown mode: When startup form closes` . As long as you replace `End` calls with something, make it `Application.Exit()` and handle closing the application more eloquently and with more options / control in your main form's `Closing` event. At least others stumbling upon this Q&A should not accept this answer without some more thought.

Comment: @DanVerdolino I agree and have amended.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Application.Exit()` instead of `End`. This allows `FormClosing` to be called no matter what (and you can handle it based on how it is being closed).

```
Private Sub frmMain_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Select Case e.CloseReason
        Case CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall
            ' This is the result of Application.Exit()
            e.Cancel = False
        Case CloseReason.UserClosing
            ' This is the result of clicking the red X
            Select Case MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you wish to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                Case DialogResult.Yes
                    e.Cancel = False
                Case DialogResult.No
                    e.Cancel = True
            End Select
        Case Else
            e.Cancel = False
    End Select
    If Not e.Cancel Then
        VarsToIni()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confused by your question, nonetheless:
This will close all your forms

```
For each x as Form in My.Application.OpenForms  
'You can then put your VarsToIni() here
 x.Close()
Next
```

Note: Add this to your import

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

Comment: **"I have tried putting it in the main window's FormClosing"** What do you think? (Yes I have but it doesn't register `End` as `FormClosing`.) Does it matter that I use the `End` from a different form? When i do `End` from another form it closes the form I'm trying to detect closing but doesn't trigger `FormClosing`.